# AngularJS checkbox placed inside ng-repeat not binding

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a checkbox (bound to a model), placed inside an `ng-repeat` tag which iterates over a list.

I want to send a value "YES" or "NO" depending on whether the box is checked or not to the controller using the `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` attributes.

But for some reason, the `$scope.value2` is not getting updated in the controller.

Here is a jsFiddle with my problem:: http://jsfiddle.net/HmvgW/

Note: If I place the checkbox outside the ng-repeat tag, the YES/NO value is sent correctly to the controller.

How do I send a value to checkbox clicked value to the controller if I place it inside the ng-repeat tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a scope issue. ng-repeat creates a new child scope with each loop. If you want to access the parent scope from within the child, you can do so with $parent.value2.

Comment: Yes, I got it working by adding the $parent.value to the input tag.

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.value2"
                   ng-true-value="YES" ng-false-value="NO" ng-click="value2Clicked()">`

Thanks!

Comment: @Wilson - thanks this really helped. What a strange bug.